# How to make a two date picker depend on each other in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose there are two date pickers. The second date picker will be fully depended on the first one as given in the snippet

```js
$( function() {
  $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
         numberOfMonths: 2,
         minDate:0,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
         }
     });
     $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
         numberOfMonths: 2,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
         }
     });  
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
           To: <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />
```

If we select a date from the first date picker is there any method if we leave empty the second date picker then the date of second date picker will set to the same date as the first but after the one year. It means if  we set the date in first is `07-29-2018` then if we left empty the second date picker then the date will automatically taken as `07-29-2019`. Is there any method for doing this. can any body please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You can use onchange or onblur event on first field to modify date on the other picker field.

Comment: @YousafHassan thankyou sir for replying I'm trying this first time so and I'm not too much familiar with this can you tell me how will i write this?

Comment: I think Kiran Shahi's answer would have helped. But instead of setting it to +1y, you can set it to the value of the first field.
But I think your concern here is just for the value sent to the backend.
If that's the case, just add a condition in your js code to check if (!$("#txtFromDate").val()){ //set value from first field }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set default date for second datepicker on select of first datepicker and vice versa. Here is an example.

```js
$( function() {
  $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
         numberOfMonths: 2,
         minDate:0,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
           $("#txtToDate").datepicker("setDate", '+1y');
         }
     });
     $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
         numberOfMonths: 2,
         onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
         }
     });  
    
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  From: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
  To: <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />
```

Comment: @manikantgautam there came conflict between your edit and my code.

Comment: i just endorsed using `date` as input type rather than `text` . You just missed including `Jquery` too.

Comment: @KiranShahi Thanks for it

Comment: @manikantgautam changing date to text make jquery ui datepicker stop working. Any way thank you for editing. You can edit if you find any error.